# Counting positive integer linear inequality solutions with constraints

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, inequality, generating-functions, integer-programming

The context is [Project Euler #600](https://projecteuler.net/problem=600), counting equiangular hexagons.

My approach is to first count solutions without congruence/symmetry and then try Burnside's lemma for congruences. The number of hexagons is the number of positive integer solutions (for fixed $n$) to
$$a + b + c + d + e + f \le n$$ with constraints
$$a+b=d+e$$
$$b+c=e+f$$
(constraint $c+d = f+a$ is redundant). Inequality can be turned into equality with a slack variable, and positive integers can be turned into non-negative integers by subtracting 1:
$$a'+b'+c'+d'+e'+f'+s=n-6$$
But how can the constraints be incorporated into one equality over non-negative integers for a  generating function counting approach? I can do a substitution like $e = a + b - d, f= c+d-a$, but this doesn't preserve the constraints $e,f \ge 1$. I think it is possible by introducing more variables but I don't see how.

WolframAlpha suggests $a'=v+w, \ b'=x+y,\ c'=v+z,\ d'=w+x,\ e'=v+y, \ f' = x+z$ but I don't know how it arrived at this. It also seems to over-count solutions: The coefficient of $x^{12}$ in g.f. $x^6 / ((1-x^3)^2 (1-x^2)^3 (1-x))$ is 31, but I count only 30 solutions with a brute-force program.

Update: I'm not sure why I didn't check this earlier, but $a+b+c+d+e+f=n$ is [A053090](https://oeis.org/A053090)(n-3). I'm still looking for a combintorial explanation of the generating function or formula.

Comment: 1) The problem should be stated in full, in the body of your question, not in a link offsite. 2) The Project Euler people have asked us not to answer project Euler questions.

Comment: The context is not actually needed for the problem at hand. The question body contains all the info required.

Comment: If project Euler have asked us not to publish any answer _and_ we wish to abide to their request, we should either close the question, or at least remove from the question any reference to projet Euler and equiangular hexagons; so that it cannot easily be googled (hoping question previous versions are not indexed).

Comment: I've read meta discussions about not allowing questions from on-going math contests. This problem was posted 6 years ago and I don't think their site has a monopoly on basic combinatorics questions that have OEIS entries.

Comment: There’s a difference between asking a combinatorics problem which happens to be similar to one in a contest and for asking for a solution to an ongoing contest problem which people are still attempting to solve.

Comment: My rationale agrees with https://euler.stephan-brumme.com/why/. Nonetheless this should be discussed on meta.

Comment: Project Euler asks that users not post their solutions in publicly viewable places.  If you don't agree with their philosophy, then it might be best that you not work on their problems.  While we have no policy here which forbids you from posting this question and answer, I find it to be in very poor taste.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is an ongoing context question.

Comment: @user1729 according to meta, this does not count as an ongoing contest. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/21384/122489

Comment: @qwr You have responded promptly to each of the comments above, dismissing each one-by-one. However, I do not understand why you didn't simply act on Jean-Armand Moroni's suggestion to edit the PE references out of the question. This would elegantly avoid the resulting debate (and after all, PE is all about elegance!).

Comment: (Also, a more recent meta question on PE has a different conclusion: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/31950/10513)

Comment: Wait for the contest to end and then we can give solutions. If it is a non-stop/years long contest, then that is being used as a cover to prevent people from sharing solutions.

Comment: @user1729 because there is no site policy against asking and answering PE problems, and I think giving hints or solutions is much better than forever bashing your head against a wall.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The parameterization is given by Jianing Song in the OEIS link and is actually quite simple. The constraints imply an invariant $t$
$$
a-d = e-b = c-f = t
$$

He considers cases $t \ge 0, t \le 0, t = 0$. It's similar to consider disjoint cases $t > 0, t < 0, t= 0$.

Suppose $t > 0$. Then naturally $a = d+t, e = b+t, c=f+t$. The solutions to $2b + 2d + 2f + 3t \le n$ can be re-parameterized as non-negative solutions to $2b' + 2d' + 2f' + 3t' + s = n-9$. Symmetric for $t < 0$.

For case $t=0$, we have $a = d, b = e, c = f$, so similarly we count positive solutions to $2a + 2b + 2c \le n$.

The final generating function is
$$
\frac{2 x^9}{(1-x^2)^3(1-x^3)(1-x)} + \frac{x^6}{(1-x^2)^3(1-x)} = \frac{x^6 + x^9}{(1-x^2)^3(1-x^3)(1-x)}
$$

---

All hexagons with congruence are uniquely parameterized from $b \le d \le f, t \ge 0$. (If $t < 0$, swap $(a,d), (b,e), (c,f)$ in a 180 deg rotation). Parameterize $d = b + y, f = d + z = b + y + z$. Then
$$a + b + c + d + e + f = 6b + 4y + 2z + 3t \le n$$
Equivalently, the non-negative solutions to
$$6b' + 4y + 2z + 3t + s = n-6$$
The final generating function is
$$\frac{x^6}{(1-x)(1-x^2)(1-x^3)(1-x^4)(1-x^6)}$$